# Pipe git rev-parse hash

Tags: git, pipe

The command

```
git cat-file -p 3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad
```

prints on screen the content of the file referred by the hash above, a `hello.txt` with just `hello world` inside.

The command

```
git rev-parse 3b18e512d
```

instead, is an astute shortcut to get the whole hash just by referring to the first hexes.

Now, how can I pass the output of `git rev-parse` to `git cat-file -p` above?

I tried with

```
git cat-file -p | git rev-parse 3b18e512d
```

but without success, even if this is usually the way I proceed with when piping outputs through different commands.

Comment: The piping happens from left to right. It does not work as you have tried. As it is written now, the output of `git cat-file` is fed as input to `git rev-parse`.

Comment: You don't *have* to: `git cat-file -p 3b18e512d` will pretty-print the contents of the abbreviated object, if the abbreviation is unique, or produce an error (as `git rev-parse` would) if not. More generally you can use shell command substitution anywhere you're using a shell: `git cat-file -p $(command_that_prints_a_valid_gitrevisions_specifier)` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Bash, you can say:

```
git cat-file -p $(git rev-parse 3b18e512d)
```

If you want `git-cat-file` to read its input from the pipeline instead, you'll have to pass the [`--batch` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file#git-cat-file---batch):

```
git rev-parse 3b18e512d | git cat-file --batch
```

Keep in mind that `--batch` is going to print out the *raw* contents of the object, while `-p` applies some formatting (aka "*pretty print*"), so the two commands don't produce the same output.

Answer (score 2):

[`git cat-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file) accepts input from `stdin` (instead of command line) only in batch mode.

This means when either the `--batch` or the `--batch-check` argument is present in its command line but in this case it rejects the `-p` argument.

`git cat-file --batch` prints the object's hash, type and size on the first line followed by the content of the object. `git cat-file --batch-check` prints only the meta information (hash, type & size) without the content.

Assuming you want only the file content you can pipe the output of `git cat-file --batch` to `tail -n +2` (to ignore the first line):

```
git rev-parse 3b18e512d | git cat-file --batch | tail -n +2
```

---

But the interesting part is that you don't need even need to run `git rev-parse` because `git cat-file` can handle partial hashes (it probably invokes the functionality of `git rev-parse` internally):

```
git cat-file -p 3b18e512d
```

is all you need.